# Column names out by one after read.csv (cause is trailing comma)

Tags: r, read.csv

I have the following minimal `.csv` file:

```
"Sl.no","Col1","Col2","Col3"
"1","one","two","three",
"2","A","B","C",
```

When I open this in Excel or Google Sheets, the file is imported correctly.

When I import it into `R` in `RStudio` using

```
temp <-  read.csv("file.csv", header = TRUE)
```

I see the following in `temp`:

[image]

The column headers are out by one.

When I remove the commas in the second and third lines, i.e. import this file:

```
"Sl.no","Col1","Col2","Col3"
"1","one","two","three"
"2","A","B","C"
```

the file is read correctly and the result for `temp` is

[image]

**Questions:**

- Is a trailing comma allowed in `.csv` files? If not are Excel and Google Sheets just forgiving?
- How can I remove the commas? I am familiar with `regex`, but not sure how to make change as a text file then read as `.csv`

Comment: you can remove the trailing comma using any text editor like sublime

Comment: R interprets the 1,2,3,... as row names, also there should always be a comma at the end of line, you are missing one comma in the first row.

Comment: According to the documentation: "If there is a header and the first row contains one fewer field than the number of columns, the first column in the input is used for the row names." - so I would either add a comma to the first row or try to delete the trailing commas. Failing that, RLave's solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding the trailing commas using `gsub` and then reading using `read.csv`

```
edited <- gsub(",,", ",", paste0(readLines("~/Desktop/file.csv"), ","), fixed = TRUE)
read.csv(textConnection(edited), header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[1:4]
#>   Sl.no Col1 Col2  Col3 
#> 1     1  one  two three 
#> 2     2    A    B     C
```

Explanation: First you use `readLines` to import the text "as is". Next you add a comma to the end of every line using `paste0`. After, you replace any instances of ",," with ",". Lastly, you use `textConnection` and `read.csv` to read the file. Note that I put [1:4] to read only the first 4 columns. For some reason I kept getting a blank fifth column (probably from the way I wrote the csv file).

Comment: Thank you all so much. I have no idea why I could not replicate the answer of @RLave. I have accepted your answer as it works for me, is a "pure" solution and I have learnt several things from it. I get the extra column too but not important as it is just for internal analysis.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest a different approach, with `read_csv` from the `readr` package:

```
library(readr) 
temp <- read_csv("file.csv")

temp
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  Sl.no Col1  Col2  Col3 
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 one   two   three
2     2 A     B     C
```

Data used:

```
"Sl.no","Col1","Col2","Col3"
"1","one","two","three",
"2","A","B","C",
```

Comment: Thanks all. Adding a comma at end of first line works although it would be good to have an automated solution. I am getting errors with `read_csv` whether I add an extra comma in the first line or not. Sample errors: 
`cols( Sl.no = col_integer(),...`, `Warning: 2 parsing failures.`

Comment: I didn't add the extra comma, I just pasted in an editor and saved it as .csv, then the function `read_csv` works without errors.

Comment: I just copied your file, then ran your two lines. I get: 
`Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  Sl.no = col_integer(),
  Col1 = col_character(),
  Col2 = col_character(),
  Col3 = col_character()
)
Warning: 2 parsing failures.
row # A tibble: 2 x 5 col     row col   expected  actual    file       expected   <int> <chr> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>      actual 1     1 NA    4 columns 5 columns 'file.csv' file 2     2 NA    4 columns 5 columns 'file.csv'`